Upgrade Log4net.dll from V1.0.2 to V2.0.16 + C# + Crystal Reports = error
We have an ASP.NET MVC application that uses Crystal Report and log4net.
When Log4net DLL is upgraded to latest V2.0.16, application throws error

Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821'

We have Crystal Engine V13 installed on Dev server. When Crystal Report engine was installed, log4Net DLL V1.0.2 was automatically installed in GAC (c://windows/assembly/log4net) - both 32 bit and 64 bit.
So, even though log4net DLL is upgraded in application references, Crystal Report continues to refer the old version from GAC and application throws error. I could not found any documentation for Crystal Report's dependency on log4net v1.02
I tried these things, but nothing worked:
Use Binding Redirect in web config.
Setting run 32 bit = true in IIS > application pool > advance setting.
How can I upgrade the assemblies in GAC? And make Crystal Report refer to the updated log4net version?
